# Need to generate a database which is allowing inconsistency i.e; violating integrity constraints

Tags: mysql, database

I want to prepare a inconsistent database which is violating key constraints (primary key,referential integrity).Generally database do not allow to generate inconsistent database but i need it to test my algorithm over inconsistent database.How can i generate a database which is violating constraints so that i can apply my algorithm over that?